# Is it possible to use DataImportHandler in Sunspot Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I have a rails app which has data in MySQL db. I am using Sunspot to interact with Solr and I would like to be able to use DataImportHandler to import data from MySQL to Solr. I have tried searching on google and I can't seem to find an answer to my question.

Ultimately, I want to be able to create a rake task that will do this data import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is interesting, but the answer is no. You would have to create your own custom `data-config.xml`. That said, so long as you stick to Sunspot field naming conventions, you should still be able to use Sunspot for searching with such a setup.

Generation of that `data-config.xml` from Sunspot's configuration would definitely be an interesting addition. Maybe for a future version.