# Data Import Handler in sunspot rails

Tags: solr, dih

I have some tables in mysql. I want to import some data using data import handler and index those using Solr. Is it possible?. I saw we need to make some modifications in data-config.xml file from this link. [Is it possible to use DataImportHandler in Sunspot Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183304/is-it-possible-to-use-dataimporthandler-in-sunspot-rails)

If so, When I execute a rails application when this data import takes place.Because with rails application I believe it is not possible to give DIH commands such as fullimport,deltaimport etc.

Please help me to resolve since I'm little confused with interaction between DIH and solr and the flow of those programs.

Comment: Supposedly it's possible but I've never been able to find a tutorial.  Any luck?

Comment: @Kevin I didn't find any..... :(